# Django auth. model when using multiple files

Tags: python, django

I have just broken up my models.py in to a module as follows:

```
models/
    __init__.py
    model1.py
    model2.py
    userModel.py
    ....
```

Where **init**.py imports all of the classes so I can still get at them using models.model1 as follows

```
from model1 import model1
from model2 import model2
from userModel import userModel
```

This is working ok however Django can no longer find the AUTH_USER_MODEL using:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.userModel'
```

I get the error:

```
LookupError: App 'app' doesn't have a 'userModel' model.
```

I have tried to change this to

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.models.userModel'
```

but this doesn't work either.  Any advice much appreciated

Jack

Comment: What do you mean the actual data?  The info detailed in the question is exactly the set up.  I can add the init file if that would help

Comment: I think it's just a typo in your question, but you missed a `.` before your imports. It should be `from .model1 import model1`. Otherwise imports won't work outside of  `app/models` directory.

Comment: Is that the case, why?

Comment: Without leading dot, this is an absolute path (starting from the current working directory or paths within `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable).  With a leading dot, this is a relative path from the directory of the file.

Comment: Ah I see, I've added those dots, error persists (see comment on your answer)

Comment: Does it work when you open a terminal with `manage.py shell` and try to import you model : `from app.models.userAccount import userAccount`

Comment: Yes both 'from app.models.Accounts import userAccount' and 'from app.models import userAccount' work so I have no idea why it cant see the auth. model

Comment: Then I don't know. All I can advise you is to respect python naming conventions. I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: Last thing, when you do `from .foo import foo` within a module named `bar` for instance, then `bar.foo` becomes ambiguous... I think your approach is not ideal and likely buggy. :/

Comment: Very possibly - one last question when I get these errors in the trace I see: return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower()).  Notice that it is trying to lower the name of the model - is there a constraint that it must be lower case?  Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I don't think so. I think it is only to allow the model name to be passed either with actual case and lower case (for content_types for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.UserModel'
```

`UserModel` is supposed to be a class that inherits from `models.Model`, not a module.

It will be passed through `django.apps.apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` that takes a string `app.Model` where `app` is a django app registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `Model` is any model within `app.models` module and submodules.

**Edit**

Before Django 1.9, your models lying in a sub-module of `app_name.models` should define `app_label = 'app_name'` in their metaclass:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app_name'
```

Comment: Yes it is a class which inherits from models.Model and before I put it in its own module it was working fine so in that sense the setup is correct.  However having all my models in one models.py file was becoming unworkable so I divided them up.  userModel.py is a module which contains the userModel class.

Comment: After edit:  Yes that is the situation, but Django is failing to find the userModel class in the models module despite me importing it in to the __init__.py file (which means I should be able to access it like models.userModel - exactly the same as before)

Comment: Your class names should start with an uppercase. And module names should be snake_cased. I think the issue is that your model has the same name as a module. Once django have found an object (whatever the type) named `userModel` within `app.models`, it does not go further in submodules, to avoid extra overhead. This is a supposition, but it makes sens. Your model name should not be named the same as your module.

Comment: This should surely work regardless of what cases I chose to use.  I have now changed the names so that the module is called 'Accounts' and it contains the class userModel - this doesn't work.  Error is:
LookupError: App 'app' doesn't have a 'usermodel' model.

Comment: This should work regardless of the case you chose to use. However, you must consider the fact that cases that do not respect the basic conventions might not have been tested. Anyway, what version of django are you using. I'm using Django 1.9 and have a custom user model called. `user.models.base.Member`. My  ̀AUTH_USER_MODEL` is set to `user.Member` and I have `from .base import *` in `user/models/__init__.py` (though I think it works even without this import). It works fine for me.

Comment: I'm using 1.8 so perhaps that could be the difference

Comment: Its to do with the 'meta' I was using!  To get your example running what meta data did you add?

Comment: I have nothing special in the metaclass of my user model. Did you set something like `app_label`?

Comment: Yes I read somewhere (http://paltman.com/breaking-apart-models-in-django/) that you had to change the app_label and/or app_name as well as the database table

Comment: OK that's it. It was changed in Django 1.9 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/ "All models need to be defined inside an installed application or declare an explicit app_label. Furthermore, it isn’t possible to import them before their application is loaded. In particular, it isn’t possible to import models inside the root package of an application."

Comment: Hmm ok so basically I should upgrade to 1.9 for the simplest solution

Comment: No, you just have to set `app_label = "app"` in the metaclass of all models that are in a submodule of `models`.

Comment: Ok cool, do you want to add that to you're answer and I'll tick it for anyone else who screws up in this unique style

Comment: I now have no errors when running python manage.py check but now migrations are broken!  It is saying: Related model 'app.usermodel' cannot be resolve.  Do my foreign keys need to change as well?

Comment: I would need the full stacktrace. Maybe it's another question.

Comment: They all have class Meta: app_label = 'app' now.  Before I did that manage.py check threw errors, now it doesnt but migrations are broken